# Bitbucket Pipeline Error With Node/Angular

Tags: angular, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I m trying to Build my angular 12 project via Bitbucket Pipeline. Upon build i m getting this warnings and finally build get failed. I know this is due to old version of node . Can any one help me how to resolve this. [image]

This is my **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The issue is because of the `Node.js` version, try to install version 12+. And I suggest you to install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) if you are running on any linux based system to keep multiple node version.

I am pretty sure when you are creating local build it must be failing. So, first create a normal build and make changes to the yml file for node.js version.

Also, if you use windows, install [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to keep node versions.

Note: Follow the warnings and compile errors for versions difference and try to run build first on locally if running fine then make sure your build script is maintaining correct versions of node.

Comment: Locally i can build this project without any issues. i m not sure by installing nvm-windows would sort out this

Comment: Yes, try that and make sure you add the correct version of `node.js` in YML or whatever your build script.